# Rcpp: are objects safely PROTECTed if I cast to/from SEXP?

Tags: rcpp

When creating an R extension in C or C++, objects created in the compiled code need to be manually protected and unprotected from the garbage collector - e.g.:

```cpp
SEXP some_func(SEXP inp)
{
    SEXP some_vec = PROTECT(Rf_allocVector(REALSXP, 100));
    // do something with 'some_vec' ...
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return some_vec;
}
```

Rcpp OTOH offers convenient classes which automatically handle the `PROTECT` and `UNPROTECT` calls, so one can safely do something like:

```cpp
Rcpp::NumericVector some_func(SEXP inp)
{
    Rcpp::NumericVector some_vec(100);
    // do something with 'some_vec' ...
    return some_vec;
}
```

Now, **if I were to cast the Rcpp objects to generic SEXP, are they still auto protected**? Example:

```cpp
SEXP some_func(SEXP inp)
{
    SEXP some_vec = Rcpp::NumericVector(100);
    // do something with 'some_vec' ...
    return some_vec;
}
```

Since `some_vec` was allocated as a specialized `NumericVector` but then casted to `SEXP`, does it still undergo automatic `PROTECT`/`UNPROTECT`, or do I need to do it manually?

And what about casting the other way around? E.g. is this safe?

```cpp
Rcpp::NumericVector some_func(SEXP inp)
{
    Rcpp::NumericVector some_vec = Rf_allocVector(REALSXP, 100);
    // do something with 'some_vec' ...
    return some_vec;
}
```

Comment: This is one of the many awesome features of `Rcpp`. It allows one to focus more on the actual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes as the only interface that there is from R uses `SEXP .Call(SEXP ...)`. So every Rcpp object automatically gets transformed (a lot with implicit conversion but also via `Rcpp::wrap(...)`) and the protection is part of that.

You can easily verify that by for once creating a `SEXP` manually *without the protection layer* and R will tell you in `R CMD check` and/or crash.

From that you can conclude that Rcpp objects are correctly protected as this does *not* happen to them.