# Do I need to protect input SEXP?

Tags: r, rcpp

In Rcpp, when running `Rf_length` on an input SEXP, do I need to further protect the input?

For example:

Would the below code be considered safe practice within Rcpp or is there a preferred method?

```
IntegerVector test(SEXP x) {
  int n = Rf_length(x);
  IntegerVector out(n);
  return out;
}
```

Comment: I looked recently at the `lobstr` [source](https://github.com/r-lib/lobstr/blob/d9ea7fb56632590f66bc4cb41f0d0a97875607c1/src/address.cpp#L25) to answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77215280/why-the-the-return-address-of-obj-addr-from-lobstr-package-is-different-to-t) question. It contains the function `obj_addrs_(SEXP x) ` which does `int n = Rf_length(x)` and does not use `PROTECT()`. So I think the answer is that you don't need to. But I'll leave this for others with more knowledge to answer more definitively.

Comment: Also see [Rcpp: are objects safely PROTECTed if I cast to/from SEXP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65612107/rcpp-are-objects-safely-protected-if-i-cast-to-from-sexp) which suggests that `PROTECT()` is not needed:  _every Rcpp object automatically gets transformed (a lot with implicit conversion but also via Rcpp::wrap(...)) and the protection is part of that_

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know! I'm still learning the basics of C++ and am finding it difficult to find examples for simple things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not think so as you are not *allocating* which is the step that needs protection --- and here the object assigned is an `int` that does not need.  The `IntegerVector` you *do* create already gets its automagically added protection.

But you could also avoid the issue and write eg

```
IntegerVector mytest(IntegerVector vec) {
  IntegerVector out(vec.length());
  return out;
}
```

depending on the type of input type you have.  And if you do not know the type at entry you can still switch based on `TYPEOF(mysexp)` and do the above.

But in sum, simple read-only accessors such as `Rf_length` can be considered safe.  The *Writing R Extensions* manual has the full gory details.  I try to minimize `SEXP` in interfaces as the added safety from `Rcpp` is 'A Good Thing (TM)'.

Comment: Also I'm definitely gonna start using the word automagically from now on. :)

Comment: Hehe.  Also check out my super-simple-just-header-wrappers repo and package [tidyCpp](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/tidycpp) which aims to make the R headers a little saner, add a _minimal_ protection layer and a little (but not much) more.  The [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyCpp/vignettes/motivation.html) has plenty of examples.  Sometimes it helps to keep simple things _simple_.